# meaning of sign in doctor's office

Tags: meaning

I visited a doctor today
 with my grandchildren and noticed this sign on the wall:

> Due to numerous missed appointments, we will begin charging $25 to anyone who fails to cancel an appointment within 24 hours."

Is it just me, or does this sign say exactly the opposite of its intention?

Comment: I kept my appointment and they said because I failed to cancel I owed them an additional $25.

Comment: is "... cancel 24 hours prior to their appointment" too much to ask for? "Within" is simply wrong.

Comment: It is improperly worded.  I *think* I can understand what it was intended to say, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @HotLicks - If you're wrong, it'll cost you 25 bucks.

Comment: I do think the misinterpretation is pretty humorous, though. You might want to mention it to the office manager. ;)

Answer (score 8):

For brevity's sake, there are certain assumptions made in the sign's wording. It is not a joke.

First, the sign is addressing those patients who may not show up for their appointments *in the future*. It is giving them a warning:

> If you miss an appointment without 24° prior notice, you will be charged $25, so please have the courtesy to cancel an appointment properly if you find you will not be keeping it. This volume of missed appointments costs us money, so we're passing that on to you when you're responsible.

It does **not** mean:

> **Every patient with an appointment** will be charged $25 if they don't cancel it within 24° of scheduling the appointment.

That would be very, very bad for business. Though it might generate some additional income immediately after posting, the practice would lose a lot of patients due to their indignation (and rightly so).

Language has context, and signs - because of brevity - are a great way to figure that what that context is.

Comment: But there are easily 5 different ways it could be reworded to at least not be saying the opposite of what it means.

Comment: @HotLicks OK. Give those 5.

Answer (score 0):

You're right: The sign does not say what the doctor thinks it says. The sign attempts deal with two classes of appointment missers: people who cancel on very short notice (that is, patients who cancel an appointment within 24 hours of its scheduled occurrence); and people who don't cancel but don't show up at all (that is, patients who miss their appointment without warning). The sign is supposed to cover both classes of patients, but the wording it uses—"anyone who fails to cancel an appointment"—garbles the two categories in question and fails to identify either one accurately.

We can improve the sign simply by expressing it in a way that lays out the two categories correctly. But identifying the reason for the new policy more clearly in the preamble seems worthwhile, too. So I recommend a revised wording along these lines:

> Due to the large number of patients who have missed appointments after giving us short or no notice of cancellation, we now charge $25 to anyone who fails to arrive in time for an appointment or who cancels an appointment within 24 hours of its scheduled occurrence.

As a practical matter, it seems to me that a policy that provides the same punishment (in the form of a $25 fee) for short-notice cancelers as for no-shows is likely to reduce the number of people who don't give any notice at all. Why bother to call the doctor's office to cancel an appointment scheduled for 18 hours later if you're going to get hit with the same fee as someone who doesn't give the office any warning at all? So the new policy may not turn out to be as beneficial as the doctor expects in terms of scheduling predictability. But that's not a matter of English language and usage.

Comment: The doctor didn't write it; most likely the office manager did. And while it could well be interpreted the way you have explained, people who call to cancel are usually treated with much more leniency than the folks who don't bother to call at all. I mean, who in their right mind would punish a patient whose out-of-town grandmother just died? Ah, the English language.

Comment: @medica How do you know the doctor didn't write it? How do you know every doctor has an office manager?

Comment: @Rathony - do you always answer comments not addressed to you? My interactions with Sven Yargs are friendly, and this comment was made in jest. But since you're so inquiring, unless I'm sorely mistaken, I do know more about doctors' offices and workings of same than you do, at least in the U.S. I would put money on the bet that the doctor didn't write it (they have more profitable things to do with their time, so usually have a staff for the other stuff). Would you?

Comment: @medica You are not here to speculate. You are here to answer the question. You could have said the doctor might not have written it. You said "The doctor didn't write it." Wow. That's speculation. What makes you think you know better than I do? Your answer is also based on guess. I don't think an answer and comment based on mind-reading or speculation are helpful. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Rathony - are you a doctor in the U.S.? Now kindly stop bothering me.

Comment: @medica What's my being doctor have to do with your speculation? I always make a comment to a non-constructive comment. I don't need to be a doctor to know what you said is speculation.

Comment: @Rathony: I have no doubt that medica is right that in all likelihood the doctor in the OP's vignette did not write the announcement—and indeed probably didn't spend more than a minute or two looking over the wording and approving it. I was speaking quite loosely in attributing the text to the doctor. It's also true that medica and I have a history of positive interactions at this site, and that I appreciate her observations about my posts. I appreciate yours as well; but I don't think her first post above need have drawn any challenge from you or from me.

Comment: @SvenYargs The point of the question is not **who posted the sign**. It is irrelevant. It is even more irrelevant whether a patient would be punished or not if (s)he misses an appointment because his/her out-of-town grandmother just died. This community is not a discussion forum and the comment is irrelevant and just speculation.

Comment: @Rathony: Well, I spent the final paragraph of my answer speculating on whether the sign would have the intended effect of cutting down on surprise no-shows for appointments—which has zero to do with the language question that the OP asked. So I'm more responsible than anyone else for diverting attention from the EL&U aspects of the question. My apologies.

Comment: -1 for incorrect usage of "within" in your proposed wording. As per the British Dictionary definition [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/within?s=t) it means "before (a period of time) has elapsed". "Within 24 hours of its scheduled appointment" therefore means "before 24 hours have elapsed", which is only compatible with *after* the scheduled appointment, not before it.

Comment: @AndyT: Thank you for explaining your downvote; I much prefer knowing what a downvoter thinks is wrong with an answer I've posted to being left to guess at it.

Answer (score -2):

Bah, it's the same thing. If you don't show up for an appointment, you have *also* failed to cancel it—within 24 hours, or ever.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.